# Angularfire 2 using AngularFireAuthGuard for role based content display

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Is there any way to use new [Angularfire2 guards](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md) (AngularFireAuthGuard) to check the user custom claims (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) for content display?

I have a button like "Edit Article" that I just want to display for users that have the "editor" custom claim.

I want something like this, but for content display not for route access control:

```
// This pipe will only allow users with the editor role to access the route
// { path: 'articles/:id/edit', component: ArticleEditComponent, ...canActivate(editorOnly) }
const editorOnly = pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.role === "editor"));
```

Comment: **[This link might help you](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/role-based-authorization-with-firestore-nosql-and-angular-5/)**

Comment: I know this method, but it doesn't use the firebase custom claims feature and the new Angularfire2 guards like I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using this for route access control, then you shouldn't use AuthGuards.  Try something like this combined with an *ngIf or *ngSwitch:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this code is standard Firebase SDK, instead of Angularfire 2. Angularfire has his methods that also can be used for this, but I'm looking for a more simple approach like the example in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an AF approach so might not be exactly what you're looking for.  This will give you the claims which you can use to decide what content to show.

```
    this.af.currentUser.then((result) => {
        result.getIdTokenResult().then((result) => { console.log(result.claims) });
    });
```